# How can I translate my navigation menu's LINKS with qtranslate on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, qtranslate

I have a bilingual (english/arabic) wordpress site. I was able to successfully translate the navigation menu items. However, the menu links on the arabic site, link to the default language which is English.

How can I tell wordpress that I need the menu links to change on the arabic site (I need the links on the arabic site to include /ar, for example: www.talalonline.com/ar instead of www.talalonline.com)

thanks

Answer (score 10):

@maha, I searched a lot about this and found the solution [here](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3604), but the answer is a little fuzzy…

As you don't want to mess with your WP core files, all changes are in the theme. Your theme is located in **wp-content/themes/*your-theme-name/***

Find your theme's **function.php** and add the code above in the end of the file, before the php end tag (**?>**):

```
class CustomLinkModifierWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function __( $text ) {
        if ( preg_match_all('~(.*?)\|(\w{2,})\|~', $text, $matches) ) {
            $text = '';
            foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $match) {
                $text .= "[:{$matches[2][$i]}]$match";
            }
            $text = __( $text );
        }
        return $text;
    }
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )    ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $this->__( $item->url )  ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Then, you have to find where's your menu view inside your theme. The theme I'm using implement's it in the **header.php**. Maybe your's uses another file name, like **header-fancy-theme.php**.

My header view code was like this:

```
<?php
$nav_sec_menu_params = array(
    'depth' => 0,
    'theme_location' => 'sec-menu',
    'container_class' => 'menu-topmenu-container',
    'menu_class' => 'menus menu-topmenu',
    'fallback_cb' => 'block_sec_menu'
);
wp_nav_menu($nav_sec_menu_params);
?>
```

All you have to do is add the Walker implementation in the param array:

```
<?php
$nav_sec_menu_params = array(
    'walker' => new CustomLinkModifierWalker(),
    'depth' => 0,
    'theme_location' => 'sec-menu',
    'container_class' => 'menu-topmenu-container',
    'menu_class' => 'menus menu-topmenu',
    'fallback_cb' => 'block_sec_menu'
);
wp_nav_menu($nav_sec_menu_params);
?>
```

Then, in your menu, you'll use **|lang|** after the language URL ,like this:

[image]

I know it's not the exactly use you were hopping of automatic language links, but this may solve your problem.

Comment: @Eduardo The URL part is not working for me, when I click the link it takes me to http://www.example.com|en|http://www.example.com/ar/|ar| instead of the language side of the site.

Comment: @KamelLabiad, did you made the changes in the code? It should be parsing the "pipes" instead of sending them to the html.

Comment: @EduardoRusso I just doped the idea of translating the menu on my site, it added more complicity to the URI, the content on my site is mostly arabic but the menus are in english and I think users they can still be able to use it that way you could see it here http://www.kamellabiad.com, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
 //tested and worked for me.
//use native wordpress filter wp_setup_nav_menu_item

 function qtrans_menuitem( $menu_item ) {

// convert local URLs in custom menu items
   if ($menu_item->type == 'custom' && stripos($menu_item->url, get_site_url()) !== false){
    $menu_item->url = qtrans_convertURL($menu_item->url);
}     
return $menu_item;
 }

 add_filter('wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'qtrans_menuitem', 0);
```

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the newbie question, where should I put this code?

Comment: @Kamel Labiad put it in your plugin

Comment: @ashrafmohammed yes which file?

Comment: @Kamel you can put it anywhere in your plugin after "Plugin Header".
to create wordpress plugin please follow this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: Cool, have you tried submitting this upstream at http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/ ?

Answer (score 1):

fork of qtranslate does this out of the box:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/

in the menu item in the field "navigation label" just provide strings for both languages:

```
[:en]English Text[:de]Deutsch Text
```

tested with qTranslate-X 2.7.8, Wordpress 4.1 and Twenty Fifteen 1.0 theme

Answer (score 0):

There are four functions in WP to translate your menu text using default or plugin option.

Each of the four functions requires at least one argument, which is the text that is to be translated. The functions are:

1. __() – (two underscores) The basic function that you will use the majority of the time. It returns the text in the correct language.
2. *e() – The same as _*() except it echoes the text instead of returning it.
3. _n() – Used when the text has the potential to be plural, so for example if you were to display how many comments have been made, you might want to output either “X comments” or “X comment” depending on how many comments you have.
4. _x() – Useful for when the translation of the word depends on the context. “Post” could mean “a post (noun)” or “to post (verb)” depending on context. It is important for the translator to know which you mean when translating to be accurate. _x() is mainly used where single words are used.

ex

```
echo __( 'Menu Text' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. however, I have already managed to translate my menu TEXT.. What I need to translate is the menu LINKS (meaning I would like to append '/ar' to the menu's links.. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am also working with qTranslate and bilingual Arabic/English site.

You can have your `.htaccess` as the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^ar[\/]?$ index.php?lang=ar
#RewriteRule ^en[\/]?$ index.php?lang=en 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And select the "Use Pre-Path Mode (Default, puts /en/ in front of URL)" options from **Advanced settings** section of your qTranslate plugin settings page.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by adding 2 menu items on for spanish and for english and french. Then I leave empty the "Navigation label" in one language in each of them. When there's no navigation label wordpress doesn't "paint" the menu item and thus when my website is presented in Spanish the "English link item" doesn't appear and when I have the website in English it happends the same with the spanish menu item.

[image]