# Translate Custom links on menu with mqtranslate plus on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual, qtranslate

Following this question [How can I translate my navigation menu's LINKS with qtranslate on wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10102752/2309097) I try to translate my navigation menu on other languages too.

I did everything that is written on the first answer:

1. Include the function on `function.php`
2. Add the `'walker' => new CustomLinkModifierWalker()` on the `header.php` file.
3. Change the name of the navigation menu to `<!- -:en- ->HOME<!- -:- -><!- -:gr- ->ΑΡΧΙΚΗ<!- -:- ->` and url to `/en|en|/|gr|`

However, the translation doesn't work. The menu shows both the strings in the navigation like `HOMEΑΡΧΙΚΗ` and the link is `/en|en|/|gr|`.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there another way to translate the menu?

Under WordPress 4.0.1

**UPDATE**

Changing the names to `[:en]HOME[:el]ΑΡΧΙΚΗ` without the above code makes the translations works, but I still cannot make the URLs works.

**UPDATE 2**

[image: menu image]

And the navmenu code:

For Greek:

```
<ul class="menu" id="nav-menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-1091"><a href="/">ΑΡΧΙΚΗ</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-1092"><a href="/#our-company">ΣΧΕΤΙΚΑ</a></li>
</ul>
```

For English:

```
<ul class="menu" id="nav-menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-1091"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-1092"><a href="/#our-company">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE 3**

I tried to add the URL with the full path including the tags, like this:

`[:en]http://www.mydomain.gr/en[:el]http://www.mydomain.gr`

But after I click on "save button", the url input is empty. It doesn't save the url path.
**UPDATE 4**

I add the code on functions.php and the line on the header.php..Now I have an optional URL on the admin page. So, I removed the URL and add the optional as the following:

`<!--:en-->/en<!--:--><!--:el-->/<!--:-->`

Then I added the code on the header.php:

```
 <?php $defaults = array(
      'theme_location'  => 'other',
      'container'       => '',
      'echo'            => true,
      'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
      'before'          => '',
      'after'           => '',
      'link_before'     => '',
      'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="nav-menu" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
    );
    wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' , 'walker' => new qTranslate_Menu_Walker() ) );
    ?>
  </div>
```

The problem is that the links in this format: `/en/#about` works but links in this format `/en/blog` doesn't work and redirect to the default language.

Comment: share the screenshot and your menu code.

Comment: I updated the question with the image. Which part of the menu code do you want? It is a huge file to add it here.

Comment: do you know how to code inspect ? if yes share the screenshot of nav html in code inspector.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Hope you mean the update

Comment: ohhh seems your problem in the `Base url`, try going into settings and check if `URL` is there.

Comment: No sorry. What you are trying to do is different. You are creating a custom link for items which do not fit in your site. Like going to your facebook page. For that you have to put full url of the page you are creating an item for. I hope you got it.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Should I also add the `[:en]` and `[:el]` tags on the full url or it will handle the translation automatically?

Comment: no, you have to put the tags

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. See the update on question

Comment: it means you have to put in one language only.

Comment: adding `tags(Invalid characters)` in url seems injection in the url which is wordpress blocking for security reasons.

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem, if you load a home with default language, this don't have a language code in url, at this time, your link work fine, but if you switch your language with language menu, your domain change to www.mydomain.com/el/ for example, your menu links show alwais the same link: /#our-company, but as you have "/" at the first of this link, if you click on it, the result is that load www.mydomain.com/el/#our-company, in my mine, this is the correct behaivor, so what it's the problem do you have?

Comment: This is the problem, that it doesn't work like this. Even if I am on a domain `www.mydomain.com/el` when I click to the menu with `/#our-company` it redirects me to the `www.mydomain.com/#our-company`

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris the only way to achieve this is to create another custom field on each menu item, and use that field for URL, does this suit your needs ? Is this fine for you ?

Comment: @Burimi If this can solve the problem, yes. Can you please add a detailed answer how I can do this? So, I can try it and see if it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried to find out if there's a filter called on the process while saving the URL field on the menu, and it seems like WordPress is doing this on it self without leaving the possibility to un-filter that.

So having that on mind I came with a solution by using an extra field called Optional URL, and if this field is filled with something (un filtered content) than WordPress will use that instead of the URL field as it normally does.

So on your functions.php at very bottom please place this code, or you can place it on another script and include it on functions :

```
    //Return the custom meta
    function um_add_optional_url( $menu_item ) {
        $menu_item->optional_url = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_optional_url', true );
        return $menu_item;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'um_add_optional_url' );

    //Update and save the optional url
    function um_update_optional_url( $menu_id, $menu_item_db_id, $args ) {
        if ( is_array( $_REQUEST['menu-item-optional-url']) ) {
            $subtitle_value = $_REQUEST['menu-item-optional-url'][$menu_item_db_id];
            update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_optional_url', $subtitle_value );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu_item', 'um_update_optional_url', 10, 3 );
    //Custom Menu Walker to get the stored values
    class qTranslate_Menu_Walker extends Walker {
        /**
         * What the class handles.
         *
         * @see Walker::$tree_type
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @var string
         */
        public $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );

        /**
         * Database fields to use.
         *
         * @see Walker::$db_fields
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @todo Decouple this.
         * @var array
         */
        public $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

        /**
         * Starts the list before the elements are added.
         *
         * @see Walker::start_lvl()
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
         * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
         */
        public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
        }

        /**
         * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
         *
         * @see Walker::end_lvl()
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
         * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
         */
        public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
        }

        /**
         * Start the element output.
         *
         * @see Walker::start_el()
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
         * @param object $item   Menu item data object.
         * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
         * @param int    $id     Current item ID.
         */
        public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
            $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
            $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

            /**
             * Filter the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
             *
             * @since 3.0.0
             * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
             *
             * @param array  $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
             * @param object $item    The current menu item.
             * @param array  $args    An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
             * @param int    $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             */
            $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
            $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

            /**
             * Filter the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
             *
             * @since 3.0.1
             * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
             *
             * @param string $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
             * @param object $item    The current menu item.
             * @param array  $args    An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
             * @param int    $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             */
            $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
            $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

            $atts = array();
            $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
            $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
            $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
            $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

            /**
             * Filter the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
             *
             * @since 3.6.0
             * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
             *
             * @param array $atts {
             *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
             *
             *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
             *     @type string $target Target attribute.
             *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
             *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
             * }
             * @param object $item  The current menu item.
             * @param array  $args  An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
             * @param int    $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             */
            $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

            $attributes = '';
            foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
                if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                    $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                    //Inject the optional URL in case it exists and the attribute is href
                    if('href' === $attr){
                        if(property_exists($item,'optional_url') && $item->optional_url){
                            $value = __($item->optional_url);
                        }
                    }
                    $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
                }
            }

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            //$item_output .= property_exists($item,'optional_url') ? $item->optional_url : "no";
            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            /**
             * Filter a menu item's starting output.
             *
             * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
             * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
             * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
             *
             * @since 3.0.0
             *
             * @param string $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
             * @param object $item        Menu item data object.
             * @param int    $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             * @param array  $args        An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
             */
            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }

        /**
         * Ends the element output, if needed.
         *
         * @see Walker::end_el()
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
         * @param object $item   Page data object. Not used.
         * @param int    $depth  Depth of page. Not Used.
         * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
         */
        public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
            $output .= "</li>\n";
        }

    } // Walker_Nav_Menu


//Custom Walker on edit screen  
add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', 'custom_nav_edit_walker',10,2 );
function custom_nav_edit_walker($walker,$menu_id) {
    return 'Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit_Custom';
}

class Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit_Custom extends Walker_Nav_Menu  {
    /**
     * @see Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference.
     */
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker_Nav_Menu::end_lvl()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference.
     */
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }
    /**
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item Menu item data object.
     * @param int $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param object $args
     */
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth;
        $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth = $depth > $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth ? $depth : $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth;

        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        ob_start();
        $item_id = esc_attr( $item->ID );
        $removed_args = array(
            'action',
            'customlink-tab',
            'edit-menu-item',
            'menu-item',
            'page-tab',
            '_wpnonce',
        );

        $original_title = '';
        if ( 'taxonomy' == $item->type ) {
            $original_title = get_term_field( 'name', $item->object_id, $item->object, 'raw' );
            if ( is_wp_error( $original_title ) )
                $original_title = false;
        } elseif ( 'post_type' == $item->type ) {
            $original_object = get_post( $item->object_id );
            $original_title = $original_object->post_title;
        }

        $classes = array(
            'menu-item menu-item-depth-' . $depth,
            'menu-item-' . esc_attr( $item->object ),
            'menu-item-edit-' . ( ( isset( $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) && $item_id == $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) ? 'active' : 'inactive'),
        );

        $title = $item->title;

        if ( ! empty( $item->_invalid ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'menu-item-invalid';
            /* translators: %s: title of menu item which is invalid */
            $title = sprintf( __( '%s (Invalid)' ), $item->title );
        } elseif ( isset( $item->post_status ) && 'draft' == $item->post_status ) {
            $classes[] = 'pending';
            /* translators: %s: title of menu item in draft status */
            $title = sprintf( __('%s (Pending)'), $item->title );
        }

        $title = empty( $item->label ) ? $title : $item->label;

        ?>
    <li id="menu-item-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="<?php echo implode(' ', $classes ); ?>">
        <dl class="menu-item-bar">
            <dt class="menu-item-handle">
                <span class="item-title"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></span>
                <span class="item-controls">
                    <span class="item-type"><?php echo esc_html( $item->type_label ); ?></span>
                    <span class="item-order hide-if-js">
                        <a href="<?php
                        echo wp_nonce_url(
                            add_query_arg(
                                array(
                                    'action' => 'move-up-menu-item',
                                    'menu-item' => $item_id,
                                ),
                                remove_query_arg($removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) )
                            ),
                            'move-menu_item'
                        );
                        ?>" class="item-move-up"><abbr title="<?php esc_attr_e('Move up'); ?>">&#8593;</abbr></a>
                        |
                        <a href="<?php
                        echo wp_nonce_url(
                            add_query_arg(
                                array(
                                    'action' => 'move-down-menu-item',
                                    'menu-item' => $item_id,
                                ),
                                remove_query_arg($removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) )
                            ),
                            'move-menu_item'
                        );
                        ?>" class="item-move-down"><abbr title="<?php esc_attr_e('Move down'); ?>">&#8595;</abbr></a>
                    </span>
                    <a class="item-edit" id="edit-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e('Edit Menu Item'); ?>" href="<?php
                    echo ( isset( $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) && $item_id == $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) ? admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) : add_query_arg( 'edit-menu-item', $item_id, remove_query_arg( $removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php#menu-item-settings-' . $item_id ) ) );
                    ?>"><?php _e( 'Edit Menu Item' ); ?></a>
                </span>
            </dt>
        </dl>

        <div class="menu-item-settings" id="menu-item-settings-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
            <?php if( 'custom' == $item->type ) : ?>
                <p class="field-url description description-wide">
                    <label for="edit-menu-item-url-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                        <?php _e( 'URL' ); ?><br />
                        <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-url-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-url" name="menu-item-url[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->url ); ?>" />
                    </label>
                </p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <p class="description description-thin">
                <label for="edit-menu-item-title-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'Navigation Label' ); ?><br />
                    <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-title-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat edit-menu-item-title" name="menu-item-title[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->title ); ?>" />
                </label>
            </p>
            <p class="description description-thin">
                <label for="edit-menu-item-attr-title-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'Title Attribute' ); ?><br />
                    <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-attr-title-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat edit-menu-item-attr-title" name="menu-item-attr-title[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->post_excerpt ); ?>" />
                </label>
            </p>
            <p class="field-link-target description">
                <label for="edit-menu-item-target-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="edit-menu-item-target-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" value="_blank" name="menu-item-target[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]"<?php checked( $item->target, '_blank' ); ?> />
                    <?php _e( 'Open link in a new window/tab' ); ?>
                </label>
            </p>
            <p class="field-css-classes description description-thin">
                <label for="edit-menu-item-classes-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'CSS Classes (optional)' ); ?><br />
                    <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-classes-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-classes" name="menu-item-classes[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( implode(' ', $item->classes ) ); ?>" />
                </label>
            </p>
            <p class="field-xfn description description-thin">
                <label for="edit-menu-item-xfn-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'Link Relationship (XFN)' ); ?><br />
                    <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-xfn-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-xfn" name="menu-item-xfn[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->xfn ); ?>" />
                </label>
            </p>
            <p class="field-description description description-wide">
                <label for="edit-menu-item-description-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'Description' ); ?><br />
                    <textarea id="edit-menu-item-description-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat edit-menu-item-description" rows="3" cols="20" name="menu-item-description[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]"><?php echo esc_html( $item->description ); // textarea_escaped ?></textarea>
                    <span class="description"><?php _e('The description will be displayed in the menu if the current theme supports it.'); ?></span>
                </label>
            </p>
            <?php
            /*
             * This is the added field
             */
            if($item->type == 'custom'):
            ?>
            <p class="field-custom description description-wide">
                <label for="edit-menu-item-custom-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'Optional URL' ); ?><br />
                    <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-custom-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-custom" name="menu-item-optional-url[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $item->optional_url; ?>" />
                    <span class="description">Place an URL to use instead of the original one, while this one does not strip tags (stays unfiltered)</span>
                </label>
            </p>
            <?php
            endif;
            /*
             * end added field
             */
            ?>
            <div class="menu-item-actions description-wide submitbox">
                <?php if( 'custom' != $item->type && $original_title !== false ) : ?>
                    <p class="link-to-original">
                        <?php printf( __('Original: %s'), '<a href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) . '">' . esc_html( $original_title ) . '</a>' ); ?>
                    </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <a class="item-delete submitdelete deletion" id="delete-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" href="<?php
                echo wp_nonce_url(
                    add_query_arg(
                        array(
                            'action' => 'delete-menu-item',
                            'menu-item' => $item_id,
                        ),
                        remove_query_arg($removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) )
                    ),
                    'delete-menu_item_' . $item_id
                ); ?>"><?php _e('Remove'); ?></a> <span class="meta-sep"> | </span> <a class="item-cancel submitcancel" id="cancel-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array('edit-menu-item' => $item_id, 'cancel' => time()), remove_query_arg( $removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) ) ) );
                ?>#menu-item-settings-<?php echo $item_id; ?>"><?php _e('Cancel'); ?></a>
            </div>

            <input class="menu-item-data-db-id" type="hidden" name="menu-item-db-id[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>" />
            <input class="menu-item-data-object-id" type="hidden" name="menu-item-object-id[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->object_id ); ?>" />
            <input class="menu-item-data-object" type="hidden" name="menu-item-object[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->object ); ?>" />
            <input class="menu-item-data-parent-id" type="hidden" name="menu-item-parent-id[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->menu_item_parent ); ?>" />
            <input class="menu-item-data-position" type="hidden" name="menu-item-position[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->menu_order ); ?>" />
            <input class="menu-item-data-type" type="hidden" name="menu-item-type[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->type ); ?>" />
        </div><!-- .menu-item-settings-->
        <ul class="menu-item-transport"></ul>
        <?php
        $output .= ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Than edit your header.php or wherever you're calling `wp_nav_menu` function and pass this new walker as a parameter :

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' , 'walker' => new qTranslate_Menu_Walker() ) );
```

Where `qTranslate_Menu_Walker` is the new walker which replaced the URL with Optional URL

PS : use the `<!--:en-->These language tags instead<!--:-->`

Comment: I will check it later today since I don't have access on the ftp now. But I will be back soon :-)

Comment: can you please check the last update? It seems that we are in a good way, but the problems should be somewhere in the header.php

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris have you placed the Walker on wp_nav_menu ? Can you be more explicit with the issue ?

Comment: What do you mean? I place the code on header.php under the defaults values. You can see it on the question on Update 4....The problem is that all the links on the home page (e.g. "www.mydomain.com", "www.mydomain.com/#about", "www.mydomain.com/#contact) works without a problem with your code. But, if I have a link to another page, the link is as it should be (e.g. "www.mydomain.com/en/blog), but when I click it, it redirects it on the default language. "www.mydomain.com/blog. Only the links to another page.

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris can you place the raw data on you're Menu Items, I`ll check this out just send me your URL's with language tags

Comment: I made a mistake on header. There were two times that it calls the navmenu. Don't know why, but probably for another page? When I change the place of the code on the second one, it worked :)

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris that's awesome.

Answer (score 2):

qtranslate have this issue for a long time, your implementation works if you have one link, but if you have different links for different languages this wont work. A way around to this problem is very simple, you just have to add menu for different languages and in the header you can call these menus depending on the current language that the user has selected.

```
<?php
if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='en') // put your code here if the current language code is 'en' (English)
{

wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Nav_en' ));

} elseif(qtrans_getLanguage()=='es') // put your code here if the current language code is 'es' (Español)
{
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Nav' ));
}
?>
```

EDIT:

Another way to make this work with a single menu would be by adding this code to your functions.php

```
// Makes menu urls work with Qtranslate
function qtranslate_menu_item( $menu_item ) {
  if (stripos($menu_item->url, get_site_url()) !== false){
    $menu_item->url = qtrans_convertURL($menu_item->url);
  }     
  return $menu_item;
}

add_filter('wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'qtranslate_menu_item', 0);
/**************************************************/
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Anastasios Ventouris,

i had checked new plugin in my wordpress setup there is one plugin named `"Transposh Translation Filter"`. It will work fine in my wordpress all the content which are loaded in wordpress site including menu , custom menu link and all those things are working fine in my wordpress.

You had just add language name in admin side and then go to widget side add this widget where you want to show your translation plugin.

Now it you choose African language at that time it will convert your site data in this language and display proper format and output in your screen.

Try this plugin and let me know your views and idea.

Answer (score 1):

mqTranslate has been deprecated in favor of qTranslate X. Instead of finding a solution for a deprecated plug-in i strongly advice you to use qTranslate X. Its more user-friendly and has additional features.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this update code..

```
<!--:en-->Ayahuasca<!--:--><!--:ru-->Аяуаска<!--:-->
```

This is updated code for menu translating.
And one more thing with translating your site use mqTranslate instead of qTranslate both have same functionality but mqTranslate has more upgraded version for wordpress.....

I hope this will help you

[image: Screen shots for menu translating]

Comment: If you read the question, you will see that I have already tried it. The problem is on the URL for a custom page and not a regular page with a simple title